# How to cast countersBindingSource.Current to object in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I saw in online tutorial a way to cast selected DataGridView Row to an object, but it doesn't work form me, by the way my object was created by LINQ. I will be appreciated for any explain or help, this is my code

```
ctr = countersBindingSource.Current as Counter;
if (ctr != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ctr.cptReference);
}
```

And this is how fill my DataGridView:

```
this.countersTableAdapter.Fill(this.mDatabaseDataSet.Counters);
```

Edit:
What's not work is the expected value. I got just null object.

Comment: Please specify in your question what exactly doesnt work. Was is the expected vs. the actual behaviour?

Comment: You seem to be binding to (typed) `DataTable`, in which case the `Current` (and elements in general) is of type `DataRowView`. Hence you need additional redirection like `ctr = (countersBindingSource.Current as DataRowView)?.Row as Counter;`